# Google Drive App says folder is empty, even though it is not

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sync, google-drive

I've recently started to use Google Drive on my devices (desktop, laptop, smartphone). It works great, but not on my phone. All folders were populated, but now some are suddenly empty (folder still there). I tried re-synchronising but nothing seems to help.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data/cache of Google Drive via Application Manager? Let me know if it works so I can add it as answer.

Comment: @geffchang No, that doesn't work.